# Fabric gradle plugin integrate with AS3.0(android-gradle-plugin-3.0)

Tags: twitter-fabric, gradle-plugin, google-fabric, android-studio-3.0, fabric-beta

**Error**:

> Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionPreviewRelease'.
>    getMainOutputFile is no longer supported.  Use getOutputFileName if you need to determine the file name of the output.

When I call `crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease`, the gradle console display these message to me,

I tried the latest fabric plugin(`io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1`), I assume that `fabric gradle plugin` didn't support the latest `android-gradle-plugin-3.0-x`.

Here is more info about new [gradle-plugin-variant-api](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_api), may be it it would help

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here.

**Edit**
Update to version 1.24.1 of the [Fabric Gradle plugin](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin) for compatibility with Gradle 3.0.+.

**Original**
Yes, the Alpha versions of Android Studio and Gradle contain breaking changes and potentially bugs. We will be on the lookout for changes to Gradle and Android Studio to see if additional changes are needed on our end or if they are resolved by those tools.

If you need to continue to use Fabric, using a more stable version of Android Studio and Gradle is recommended.

Comment: Thanks Mike, So how long can use the new fabric-beta-plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow your comment. Can you please clarify?

Comment: When will the new fabric-beta-plugin release?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, we will wait for things to stabilize on Gradle before doing a release. We test against beta and stable versions.

Comment: Gradle 4.1 is in stable version now.
When can we expect Fabric Plugin to be compatible with new Gradle?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the thread. Updating to Fabric plugin 1.24.1 should do the trick. Release notes: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin

Comment: Ok, so updating plugin did the job, but there is another thing that failed during the process. Now Crashlytics cannot find apk file needed for BETA release, with an exception "Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't find the specified file..."

Comment: @MichałHawryszko I haven't seen that one locally. Can you share the full error (perhaps post a new question if needed?)

Comment: @MikeBonnell it works locally, the problem was on our CI. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @MichałHawryszko how did you solve the problem on your CI? I have the same problem - using Jenkins.